# Ionic features not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to create a application using ionic by following a tutorial. When I use ionic serve, the application loads in my browser and works as expected. I can use the pull down to refresh and the infinite scoll.

The weird thing is that when I build it to an apk (ionic build android) and run it on my mobile phone, it won't work. The data is loaded, but the pull to refresh and infinite scroll isn't working.

I put my code up on pastebin hoping some of you would know what I'm doing wrong here

HTML:  [My index.html](http://pastebin.com/kY91LqbT)
JS: [My app.js](http://pastebin.com/chqy2uKu)

Comment: Do you have some log's from webview console? Your code looks alright.

Comment: When I use ionic serve I don't really get any errors. I only get this warning:  
`SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.`  
  EDIT:
I was too soon posting my answer. After I pull to refresh I get the following error:  
`ReferenceError: callback is not defined  
    at app.js:21  
    ..........
`

Comment: I meant when running in Android,  you can inspect the webview  on your phone

Comment: I get the same error when inspecting the webview on my phone. Here is a screenshot of the error: http://imgur.com/hCyWI56